# ¿Cómo hacer que un acumulador se reinicie luego de terminar la evaluación de un ciclo?

Tags: algoritmos, pseint

Tengo una asignación para la cual debo llenar dos matrices con respuestas cerradas (`1` es sí y `0` es no), luego de llenar estas matrices debo comparar las respuestas dadas por los participantes y luego de ello comparar, si un participante hombre `N` respondió exactamente igual a una participante mujer `M`, entonces son almas gemelas.

Hasta ahora he realizado esto en *Pseint*:

```
Proceso Taller1

//Primero se definen las variables a utilizar como contadores en los ciclos para llenar las matrices.
Definir i,j,k,l,n,m, car, valori, valorf, resp Como Entero;

Escribir "Indique la cantidad de hombres encuestados";
Leer n;
Escribir "Indique la cantidad de mujeres encuestadas";
leer m;

//Se delimita la cantidad de características a consultar a los encuestados
car=4;

//Se inicializa la variable respuesta que captura las respuestas de los encuestados
resp=0;

//Se definen los arreglos matriciales
Dimension Hombres[n,car];
Dimension Mujeres[m,car];
Dimension result[n];

//Se llena la matriz de hombres según sus respuestas
Para i=1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 hacer
    Para j=1 Hasta car Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "El hombre #", i, " Tiene el gusto por la característica# ",j," (responda 1 para Si, y 0 para No)";
        Leer resp;

        //Se condiciona el ingreso de datos para evitar respuestas fuera del rango
        si resp >1 entonces
            Hacer
                Escribir "Indique valor 1 para Si o 0 para no SOLAMENTE!!!!!";
                Leer resp;
                si resp<=1 Entonces
                    Hombres[i,j]=resp;
                FinSi
            Hasta Que  resp<=1;
        Sino
            Hombres[i,j]=resp;
        finsi
    FinPara
FinPara

//Se llena la matriz de mujeres segun sus respuestas
Para i=1 Hasta m Con Paso 1 hacer
    Para j=1 Hasta car Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "La Mujer #", i, " Tiene el gusto por la caracteristica# ",j," (responda 1 para Si, y 0 para No)";
        Leer resp;
        si resp >1 entonces
            Hacer
                Escribir "Indique valor 1 para Si o 0 para no SOLAMENTE!!!!!";
                Leer resp;
                //se condiciona el ingreso de datos para evitar respuestas fuera del rango
                si resp<=1 Entonces
                    Mujeres[i,j]=resp;
                FinSi
            Hasta Que  resp<=1;
        Sino
            Mujeres[i,j]=resp;
        finsi
    FinPara
FinPara
```

Y lo que quiero es que mediante un ciclo un acumulador sume `1` cada vez que exista un *match* entre las respuestas de los encuestados, y que ese acumulador guarde ese resultado y luego se reinicie para evaluar al sujeto `n+1` y a la mujer `n+1`. He hecho algo y lo detallo adelante, solo que cuando lo hago así el acumulador no se reinicia y suma lo que viene arrastrando del primer ciclo.

```
Para i=1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para j=1 Hasta car Con Paso 1 Hacer
        k=Hombres[i,j];
        l=Mujeres[i,j];
        si k == l Entonces
            valori=valori+1;
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinPara
```

Comment: tu acomulador es `valori` ??

Comment: Si ese es el acumulador cada vez que existe un match entre las respuestas suma 1, al final si valori = car(numero de características) entonces son almas gemelas

Comment: Lo que me causa duda es lo siguiente tienes el acumulador de match! eso es perfecto, pero luego con ese mismo valor quieres reiniciarlo? donde esta la persistencia de ese dato entonces?

Comment: Exacto es lo que quiero hacer, yo tenia pensado almacenarlo en un arreglo de resultados donde se guarden y luego verificarlos mediante una corrida donde pueda determinar si son almas gemelas o no

Comment: Tu guardas la cantidad de respuestas iguales en algun lado? por ejemplo hombre 1 tiene 10 respuestas iguales con mujer 5? esa es tu intension?

Comment: La verdad, había pensado es guardar lo que suma el acumulador, así se que si el acumulador 'valori' es igual a las características 'car' entonces esos dos evaluados son almas gemelas, esto lo pensé que porque un solo encuestado puede tener varias almas gemelas.

Comment: Y donde guardas ese valor?

Comment: Quisiera guardarlo en un arreglo (vector o matriz) que registre las respuestas de "Hombre n con mujer m", pero no consigo la manera de hacerlo allí tengo el problema, luego de que la guarde entonces puedo reiniciar el acumulador, al hacer eso termino el ejercicio

Comment: Te deje un codigo que probe, espero qiue te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que vi en tu codigo es que tu recorres `n` que es la cantidad de `Hombres` y `car` que es la cantidad de `Caracteristicas` Lo que yo hice fue recorrer `Hombres`, `Mujeres` y `Caracteristicas` entonces comparo

Hombre 1 con Mujer 1 y traigo las respuestas de caro uno e imprimo su cantidad de coincidencias y las imprimo, ahi puedes guardarlas como tu quieras.

```
Para hombre = 1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para mujer = 1 hasta m Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Para j=1 Hasta car Con Paso 1 Hacer
                k=Hombres[hombre,j];
                l=Mujeres[mujer,j];
                si k == l Entonces
                    valori=valori+1;
                FinSi
            FinPara
        Escribir "Para Hombre " hombre, " y mujer " mujer, " hay " valori " coincidencias"
        valori = 0;
    FinPara
FinPara
```

No se mucho `pseudocodigo` pero tu deberias guardar en tu `matriz` o `vector` los valores que yo imprimo.

Comment: Claro, he alli mi error estaba haciendo mal el recorrido me faltaba ese tercer ciclo perfecto... haciendo la prueba lo que hago es guardar las coincidencias y de alli condiciono si son almas gemelas o no...!!!

Comment: Exacto! yo ya lo probe jajaja entretenido igual xD